# Contamination in a graph using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to simulate the diffusion of a virus in a network. I've modified a random graph generator to create a graph in which each node represents an individual. Now I would like to be able to click on a node (which infects him) and to see the propagation of the virus in the graph. For exemple, each neighbour of an infected node is infected with a probability p chosen before. For the moment, I can only click on a node and it turns red, but that's it. Any ideas ? 
Here is the javascript code :

```
var width = 1300, 
height = 1000; 

n = 30
m = 100
charge = -2000
z = 0,7 // contamination parameter

function changevalue() {
n = document.getElementById("numberofnodes").value;
m = document.getElementById("numberoflinks").value;
charge = document.getElementById("chargenumber").value;
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("dblclick", create);


create();

function create () {
  svg.selectAll(".link, .node").remove();
  randomGraph(n, m, charge);
}

function randomGraph (n, m, charge) {
  var nodes = d3.range(n).map(Object),
      list  = randomChoose(unorderedPairs(d3.range(n)), m),
      links = list.map(function (a) { return {source: a[0], target: a[1]} });

  var force = d3.layout.force()
      .size([width, height])
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .charge(charge)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();

  var svgLinks = svg.selectAll(".link").data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  var svgNodes = svg.selectAll(".node").data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 2)
      .style("fill", "green")
      .style("fill", function(d) {return d.color; })
      .each(function() {
    var sel = d3.select(this);
    var state = false;
    sel.on("click", function() {
      state = !state;
      if (state) {
        sel.style("fill", "red");
      } else {
        sel.style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
      }
    });
  });

  svgNodes.transition().duration(2000)
      .attr("r", function (d) { return 0.8 * d.weight })

  svgLinks.transition().duration(20000)
      .style("stroke-width", 1);

  function tick () {
    svgNodes
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y });

    svgLinks
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y });

  }
}


function randomChoose (s, k) { 
  var a = [], i = -1, j;
  while (++i < k) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length);
    a.push(s.splice(j, 1)[0]);
  };
  return a;
}

function unorderedPairs (s) {
  var i = -1, a = [], j;
  while (++i < s.length) {
    j = i;
    while (++j < s.length) a.push([s[i],s[j]])
  };
  return a;
}
```

Comment: You might appreciate this small game built with a similar approach / goal in mind: https://vax.herokuapp.com/game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach is to create a function that takes in an array 'infected' nodes and for each infected node:

- examines the links to look for this node is linked
- where a link is found, randomly add the linked node to the array of newly infected
  nodes, and repeat the function.  The random can be based on whatever probability you want - currently the example below uses 0.5.
- repeat this function a limited number of times, else it will continue
  forever

The example below assigns a colour to the infected nodes based on which iteration of the function that node is infected.

```js
console.clear()
var width = 600,
  height = 500;

n = 30
m = 100
charge = -2000
z = 0, 7 // contamination parameter

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

var count = 0
var iterations = 5

var links, nodes

var colour = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1, 10])
  .range(["red", "steelblue"])
  .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

create();

function create() {
  svg.selectAll(".link, .node").remove();
  randomGraph(n, m, charge);
}

function randomGraph(n, m, charge) {
  var nodes = d3.range(n).map(function(d) {
    let obj = {}
    obj.r = 15
    obj.state = false
    return obj
  });
  list = randomChoose(unorderedPairs(d3.range(n)), m),
    links = list.map(function(a) {
      return {
        source: a[0],
        target: a[1]
      }
    });



  var force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(30))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .on("tick", tick)

  var svgLinks = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")

  var svgNodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("id", d => "node-" + d.index)
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 2)
    .style("fill", "grey")
    .on("click", startVirus)

  svgNodes.transition().duration(2000)
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return 0.8 * d.r
    })

  svgLinks.transition().duration(2000)
    .style("stroke-width", 1);

  function tick() {
    svgNodes
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y
      });

    svgLinks
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y
      });

  }
}

function startVirus(node) {
  d3.selectAll('circle').style("fill", function(d) {
    d.state = false
    return "grey"
  })
  let id = node.index
  count = 0;
  console.clear()
  infectCircles([id])
}

function infectCircles(carrierIDs) {
  count = count + 1
  let potentialInfections = []

  carrierIDs.forEach(function(c) {
    let circleID = "#node-" + c
    d3.select(circleID)
      .transition(2000)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.state == true) {
          return d.colour
        } else {
          d.state = true
          d.colour = colour(count)
          return d.colour
        }

      })

    links.forEach(function(l) {

      if (l.source.index == c) {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
          console.log("infect! " + l.target.index)
          potentialInfections.push(l.target.index)
        }

      }
      if (l.target.index == c) {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
          console.log("infect! " + l.source.index)
          potentialInfections.push(l.source.index)
        }
      }
    })

    if (count <= iterations) {
      infectCircles(potentialInfections)
    }

  })

}


function randomChoose(s, k) {
  var a = [],
    i = -1,
    j;
  while (++i < k) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length);
    a.push(s.splice(j, 1)[0]);
  };
  return a;
}

function unorderedPairs(s) {
  var i = -1,
    a = [],
    j;
  while (++i < s.length) {
    j = i;
    while (++j < s.length) a.push([s[i], s[j]])
  };
  return a;
}
```

```css
circle {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I’m also wondering if it is possible to show the progression of the infection (ie there is a delay between each step of contamination, so one can see how the contamination evolves through time)

Comment: Hi - probably, either using a timer and/or d3.transition for each loop.